# Marquee Component in Richfaces or primefaces

Tags: primefaces, richfaces, marquee

I am working with `jsf 2` , is there any `marquee` component in `richfaces` or `primefaces`

Answer (score 0):

No such component in RichFaces. But you can easily use a jQuery plugin, like [this one](https://plugins.jquery.com/marquee/).

Answer (score 0):

There is no special component in the Primefaces or Richfaces Framework to realize such a behaviour.

Even though you are also not forced to use JSF Components only. You could just wrap a JSF component into a normal HTML Element.

For example:

```
<marquee>
    <h:outputText value="Hello World" />
</marquee>
```